# Search data based on form values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, search

I have a search form where you can select different cities and a house-type. Can anyone tell me how I can put the entered form data into the URL and display the filtered data with the GET method in Laravel?

Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code service. You need to put in your efforts and then ask your question where you get stuck.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will edit the post where I got stuck.

Comment: whether you get the solution or not??

Comment: I have tried a million things. I will edit to the best shot. Stuck forever.

Comment: wait i update my solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $selectedcities=[]; 
    if (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::has('city')) {
    foreach (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('city') as $c) {
      $selectedcities[] = $c;
    }
  }
?>
```

```js
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.refine-your-search input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    var prm = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    searchByCheckbox(prm);
  });
});

function searchByCheckbox(prm) {
  var searchString = '';
  var searchString = $('#'+prm+'String').val();
  if (searchString != '') {
    searchString = searchString + '&';
  }
  var tmpQString = '';
  $('#'+prm+' input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    if(tmpQString != ''){
      tmpQString = tmpQString + '&';
    }
    
    tmpQString = tmpQString + prm + '[]=' + $(this).val();
  });

  // alert(tmpQString);
  searchString = searchString + tmpQString;
  var searchUrl = baseUrl + '?' + searchString;
  window.location.replace(searchUrl);
  return window.location.href = searchUrl;
}

</script>
```

```html
<div id='city'>
  <!-- use foreach for all cities -->
  <input type="checkbox" value="Cityname" name="city[{{ $city->id }}]" {{ (in_array($city->id,  $selectedcities)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}>
  <label>{{$city->name}}</label>
  <input type="hidden" id="cityString" name="cityString" value="<?php echo http_build_query(Request::except(['city']));?>">
  <!-- end foreach -->
</div>
```

```
<!-- In Controller you can get -->
<?php 
  $city = $request->city; //and use it in your query LIKE
?>
```

Comment: Code only answers are bad. Please explain your answer. Also your code is really bad formatted!

Answer (score 0):

> Hope it give some idea to you

**view**

```
            {!! Form::open(['url' => ['yoururl'], 'method' => 'get', 'role' => 'form' ,'id' => 'search']) !!} 
                <select class="form-control" name="city">

                  <option value="">--Select--</option>
                   @foreach($cityas $cs)
                    <option  value="{{$cs['cityid']}}">{{$cs['city']}}</option>
                   @endforeach

              </select>

                   <input type="text" name="zip" class="form-control fldcls clrfield">
                   <input type="hidden" id="hasvalues" name="search" value="1">
                   <button type="button" onclick="submitSearch()"  class="btn rsi-submit-btn">Search</button>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Script**

```
function submitSearch(){
  $("#search").submit();
}
```

**Controller**

In your controller

```
public function functionname(Request $request)
        if($request->input('search') && $request->input('search') == '1'){
             $result = modalname::modal function name( $request );

       //Get the data using modal and passed it to the view page

          }
     $data['result']    = $result;
    return view('your view page', $data);
}
```